# Creating Strikethrough Macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a novice to VBA and I'm trying to make a simple macro where one can highlight a set of cells, click a button, and strikethrough the selected sells. After, you can select the cell again, click the same button, and remove the strikethrough.

I have been looking for decent documentation but, have yet to find anything.

Here's some code.

Also, I would love to know where the best documentation is on VBA.

```
Sub strikeOut()

Selection.Font.Strikethrough = True

End Sub
```

I also need help with the command button.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right path. Based on your code, I'm assuming you already have a command button created. If so try this:

```
Sub strikeOut()
    With Selection.Font
        .Strikethrough = Not .Strikethrough
    End With
End Sub
```

To create a command button:

- **Excel 2003 and earlier**:

  - Open up the `Visual Basic` toolbar and activate the `Control Toolbox` button. Another box/toolbar should appear with different control options.
  - Select the `Button` option and place it in the desired location.
- **Excel 2007 and later**:

  - Click on the `Developer` tab/ribbon.
  - Select `Insert` and select `Button` and place it in the desired location.
- *The steps below apply to all versions from this point forward.

  - Right-click on your new button and select `Properties` to give your button a name/caption.
- Right-click again and select `View Code`.
- In the `ButtonName_Click()` sub, add the `strikeOut()` call using either:

  - `Call strikeOut()`
- or simply

  - `strikeOut`

To answer the second part of your question, it's hard to say what is the 'best' but here are some links that may help:

[Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com)
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com)
[OZgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/)

Comment: @STANGMMX There should be a stop/play/pause button at the top of your code editor window. Click the stop button and try again.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Now it says invalid or unqualified reference.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? It sounds like there's something else going on that I can't see here.

Comment: Got it. Silly typo. Thank you very much. I left off the period at the beginning of .Strikethrough. Like I said, I'm not used to VBA syntax.

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained + Good Followup in comments :)