# Is there a way to split contents of a cell which has part of its text strikenthrough?

Tags: excel, vba, strikethrough

I know if I check the strikethrough property of Font like, for example `range("C1").Font.Strikethrough` I'll have `True` if all the cell is strikethrough and a `False` if it's not but checking it in a cell like this:

[image: Text part strikenthrough]


The result of the property is `Null`.

Now, knowing this, is there a way to recognize if just part of the content cell is "strikethrough" and then parse it so I could replace with other text?

I know I can check each character (checked out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143643/excel-vba-delete-strikethrough-characters-in-a-cell)) if it has the property active but, how could I know which part of the text is strikethrough and then replacing that text with another one?

Comment: What are your trying to put in its place?  Is it going to be the same across all cells or are you going to replace it with the same text just not striken through?

Comment: With another text maybe from another cell. If it would be the same text but not strike through I could use something like this I think: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829914/creating-strikethrough-macro-in-excel#11830061)

Comment: Range("c1").Characters(start,length ).font.strikethrough, may be a good place to start, but youll need to loop the start, with length of 1.  You can then use MID from 1 to this point and add your replacement on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was thinking about how I would do this and I came up with the following function.

```
Function strkThr(t As Range) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim y As Boolean
Dim temp As String

y = False
temp = ""
For i = 1 To Len(t.Value)
    If Not t.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = y Then
        temp = temp & "|"
        If y Then
            y = False
        Else
            y = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not y Then
        temp = temp & Mid(t, i, 1)
    End If
Next

strkThr = temp
End Function


Sub replace()
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("A1:A100")
    cel.Value = strkThr(cel)
    cel.Value = replace(cel.Value, "||", YOURVALUE)
Next cel
End Sub
```

The function replaces each grouping of strike through text with "||".  Then in the sub you would replace the "||" with the value wanted.

Comment: Clever workaround. So you search of any character with strikethrough, replace it with something that is more easy to handle and then replace it, right?

Comment: @Kronos Yes it puts A "|" at the beginning of the group and a "|" at the end of the group. And everything in between is skipped.  You end up with "||" in place of the whole group, then replace that with your wanted values.

Comment: Do you know why does .Characters.Font.Strikethrough works but if I use Left().Font.Strikethrough doesn't? I understand Left returns a string but, would you know if there's another way to check if a substring has the strikethrough property?

Comment: All the research I have done states that to get or set the format properties of the characters one needs to use the characters.

Comment: But could someone set the properties of those characters by getting a substring in some way?

Comment: Not in vba, as I understand it.